# iPhone 5C behaving like headphones are plugged in

Tags: iphone, audio, headphones

I updated my 5c to iOS 9.3.2 and since then the phone has been behaving as though the headphone are plugged in.

Neither speaker nor microphone work normally when taking calls - I hear nothing and the caller cant hear me. But when I switch it to speaker during a call it works fine, and I can hear the ring tone. Sounds in apps like Spotify dont work either.

Of course I've turned the phone on and off again.

Would anyone know what I can do?

Comment: Did you try plugging in a headset and unplugging it again?

Comment: I tried it before and no result. Tried again just then and it worked! Thanks

Comment: Did you check if the entrance is clean? Did you tried to blow on it? Did you tried to check any damages on it? Did you tried any software solution you can think of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try plugging in a headset and unplugging.

Comment: This was already said in a comment.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel right, my comment, when OP confirmed that it solved the problem I made it an answer.

Comment: You're right. I didn't read it all. My bad. Flag mine as obsolete when you see it.

Comment: I'll add that I had to jiggle the headphone jack around a bit as well